# One wire temperature sensor DS18B20 sudden precission drop

Tags: temperature, ds18b20, 1-wire

I wired 10 DS18B20 to the raspberry pi, in the normal powered mode. I am using the Raspbian's built in w1-gpio and w1-therm. I am able to read all the 10 sensor values.

Problem is, after (seemingly random) few hours of continuous pooling, I observe that all my sensors drop precision to 9 bit and only show temperatures with 0.5 Celsius precision. I can revert the sensors back to the default precision by interrupting their power for a short while.

Anyone knows what might cause this? I started to introduce little changes, to detect the cause, but the long time required for this to happen makes the process tedious.

[image]

Comment: i know its been a while, but just in case this is still an issue (with the newest kernel), can you post the exact values for each slaves "w1_slave" file, e.g. via "cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-*/w1_slave"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a [short](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=73140&p=526179)? Seems like a similar problem...

Comment: Thanks! Checked, it's not a short. Also there is no mechanical movement during the transition between precisions. I am thinking maybe this guy had similar problem and was actually solved by resetting the DS18B20 during the wire debbugging.